# Setting different images for different geolocations/countries in the app store

Tags: app-store

If I make one app that is for different countries but for example is sponsored by "Lyft" in the US and "UBER" in the UK can i make changes to the app store images in each location to show Lyft in the US and UBER in the UK so i can avoid making more than one app ?

If not what is the best workaround for this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not directly about programming or coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible to upload different screenshots for different localisations.

First of all you have to add **additional localisations** for the languages / countries you want to target in iTunes Connect.

[image]

Then go to the new Media Manager to upload different screenshots for the different localisations. (And not "just" take the ones from your primary locale)